# aspnet 5 RESTful api ModelState.IsValid == true even though values are not valid according to DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I have used fiddler and swagger to attempt testing and get the same results.

Here is the model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace AdGeo.Configuration.WebApi.Model
{
    public class ValueAdd
    {
        public string test { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Range is required")]
        [Range(0,9,ErrorMessage ="Range 0 to 9")]
        [Display(Name ="Test Required")]
        public int? testrequired { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here Is the Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using AdGeo.Configuration.WebApi.Model;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace AdGeo.Configuration.WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody]ValueAdd valueAdd)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return new CreatedAtActionResult("Get", "Values", new { id = 5 }, valueAdd);
            }
            return new BadRequestObjectResult(ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Json:

```
{
  "test": "string",
  "testrequired": 100
}
```

It gets to the ModelState.IsValid which equals true, I am expecting it to equal false since 100 is outside the range.

Also, if I try to post this Json:
Sample Json:

```
{
  "test": "string"
}
```

I would expect the ModelState.IsValid to be false, however it equals true.

I have been searching and searching to no avail, the closest I have seen is people trying to create an action filter, but those are mostly solution for prev MVC6 and not the same.

What am I missing, please note this is my first post on StackExchange, so apologies on any formatting issues.  Please let me know what needs clarification and I will edit accordingly.

Thank You!

Comment: Have you checked to see what the model state errors are? You can get it via` var errors = ModelState.Where(e => e.Value.Errors.Count > 0).ToList();`.

Comment: Thanks for the question, the issue is that the ModelState doesn't think there are any errors.  It keeps returning true for ModelState.IsValid, unless I am misinterpreting what you are asking? Just to verify I tried executing what you suggest but  Where is not a method on ModelState.

Comment: Hah, you're right! I misread your question. The only suggestion I have at the moment is to put a breakpoint in the HttpPost method and take a peak at the values in `valueAdd` to see if it's what they're what you're expecting.

Comment: I have done that and it shows testrequired = null.  Which I understand because the property is public int?  but i thought the [required] and [rande()] tags would enforce it to have a value in the specified range?  As a reminder I'm using dnxcore50 and MVC6 if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, I think it's because I'm using AddMvcCore rather than AddMvc. To work it out, I've created the following action filter attribute. It will check if the model is null and required and it will run validation when not null.

```
/// <summary>
/// Validate inputs and update ModelState with errors
/// </summary>
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var parameters = context.ActionDescriptor.Parameters.Cast<ControllerParameterDescriptor>().ToDictionary(p => p.Name);

        foreach (var kvp in context.ActionArguments)
        {
            if (kvp.Value == null)
            {
                if (!parameters[kvp.Key].ParameterInfo.IsOptional)
                {
                    context.ModelState.AddModelError($"{kvp.Key}", "Parameter is required");
                }

                continue;
            }

            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var vc = new ValidationContext(kvp.Value);
            if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(kvp.Value, vc, results))
            {
                var errs = from vr in results
                           from member in vr.MemberNames
                           select new { Member = member, vr.ErrorMessage };

                foreach (var err in errs)
                {
                    context.ModelState.AddModelError($"{kvp.Key}.{err.Member}", err.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```